# Boost confilct and omnimapper on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I tried to install omnimapper(https://github.com/CognitiveRobotics/omnimapper), it only compiles with boost 1.48. But ROS has many packages which need boost 1.46. For instance, If we would like to use Kinect, the ros-hydro-openni-launch shall be installed, but at the same time libboost1.48-all-dev will be automatically removed .

```
  They don't support ubuntu 12.04. Has anyone tried successfully using ubuntu 12.04? Thanks a lot!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196386/boost-confilct-and-omnimapper-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2014-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See: http://answers.ros.org/question/170406/ros-hydro-and-boost-148/

You'll either have to modify Omnimapper to work with an older version of boost, build ROS from source, or upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu where the version of boost that you need is the default version.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1